# Controle global para ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading

Rodo um software localmente em Java SE, basicamente ele é o sinótico de um equipamento em campo, podendo ser controlado por esse software. O usuário tem varias funções dentro dele, podendo ligar, mudar status, configurações, etc.

Cada função é executada por uma thread separada, para não comprometer a UI. Gostaria de centralizar a criação dessas threads de comando criando uma classe `global` que retornaria o [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Vale a pena transformar isso em âmbito "global" dentro da minha aplicação, ou trabalhar com os `Executors` separados por comando seria o mais correto?

Examplo de uma classe global de `ExecutorService`(básica):

```java
    class GlobalThreadPool {

      int maximumPoolSize = 4;

      final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Orders-%d").setDaemon(true).build();

      final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maximumPoolSize, threadFactory);

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o programa possui várias interações diferentes com threads, faz sentido centralizar e encapsular esta funcionalidade em uma classe especializada.

Sobre o nome, eu evitaria qualquer coisa com nome de "global" e, neste caso, expondo detalhes de implementação.

A priori, eu modelaria esta classe primeiramente definindo interfaces para o gerenciador que executa as funções do programa e para os comandos. Exemplo:

```
interface Comando {
    void executar();
}

interface GerenciadorExecucao {
    void executar(Comando c);
}
```

Note que as interfaces não dizem como os comandos serão executados. Tal detalhe será gerenciado pela implementação e as outras classes não tem nada a ver com isto, para elas isto é transparente, elas apenas esperam que o comando seja executado.

Quanto à implementação, eu criaria uma classe chamada `GerenciadorExecucaoAssincrono` contendo um thread pool cujas threads consumem os comandos de uma fila sincronizada como [`LinkedBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html). Exemplo;

```
class GerenciadorExecucaoAssincrono implements GerenciadorExecucao {
    private final int maximumPoolSize = 4;
    private final ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactoryBuilder().setNameFormat("Orders-%d").setDaemon(true).build();
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maximumPoolSize, threadFactory);
    private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Comando> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>()

    public GerenciadorExecucaoAssincrono() {
        //thread que fica em loop infinito consumindo os comandos da fila
        executorService.submit(() -> {
            while(true) {
                Comando c = queue.take(); //espera por um comando na fila
                c.executar();
            }
        });
    }

    public void executar(Comando c) {
        //adiciona o comando à fila, desbloqueando a thread acima
        queue.put(c);
    }
}
```

Agora você pode criar qualquer implementação de comando em outras classes. Dessa forma, cada funcionalidade do seu sistema pode usar a nova API de execução assíncrona e de forma desacoplada.

No exemplo acima, eu criei uma única thread consumindo os comandos, então o resultado é que os comandos são executados na mesma ordem em que são adicionados à fila.

NO entanto, você pode ter várias threads e executá-los em paralelo, basta submeter várias vezes o mesmo `Runnable` que eu coloquei no lambda acima. O problema disso é que os comandos executados ao mesmo tempo poderiam ter um efeito indesejado, já que você tem um equipamento físico e possíveis limitações. Cabe a você analisar isto e pensar na melhor estratégia.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta. Entendi perfeitamente sua colocação, realmente dessa forma consigo deixar os comandos desacoplados. Alguns equipamento usam `TCP/IP` outros usam `Serial` para comunicação, por diversos fatores, dessa forma não conseguiria usar elas em paralelo, por que eu só teria uma porta de saída igual. Ainda terei que pensar em alguma coisa como prioridade para esses comandos, mas isso fica para uma próxima pergunta, depois que eu tentar implementar alguma lógica para isso. Obrigado novamente.