# Jantar dos Filósofos usando ArrayBlockingQueue

Tags: java

Tenho que resolver o problema abaixo do Jantar dos Filósofos, usando `synchronized`; monitor (Condition, Lock); e criando uma classe Semaforo com `ArrayBlockingQueue`.

As duas primeiras consegui fazer, agora a classe Semaforo com ArrayBlockingQueue eu não consegui.

Não postei as classes resolvendo usando Condition, Lock e usando synchronized, para não desviar do foco, mas basicamente, elas permitem o uso dos métodos pegaGarfo e largaGarfo pelos filósofos sem causar deadlock.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender e resolver o problema?

Classe FilosofoGlutao

```
class FilosofoGlutao implements Runnable {

    final int N = 5; // são cinco filosofos e cinco garfos...
    public List<Garfo> garfos; // garfos dispon�veis 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4
    public final int filosofo;
    public FilosofosGlutoes.TSolucao vraSolucao;

    FilosofoGlutao(List<Garfo> gs, int fil, FilosofosGlutoes.TSolucao solucao) {
        garfos = gs;
        filosofo = fil;
        this.vraSolucao = solucao;
    }

    private void executaGarfo(boolean booPega) throws InterruptedException {

        switch (vraSolucao.tpSolucaoEnum) {
            case SYNCHRONIZED:
                if (booPega) {
                    ((SolucaoSynchronized) vraSolucao.vraObject).pegaGarfo(filosofo, garfos.get(filosofo), garfos.get((filosofo + 1) % N));
                } else {
                    ((SolucaoSynchronized) vraSolucao.vraObject).largaGarfo(filosofo, garfos.get(filosofo), garfos.get((filosofo + 1) % N));
                }
                break;
            case MONITOR:
                if (booPega) {
                    ((SolucaoMonitor) vraSolucao.vraObject).pegaGarfos(filosofo, garfos.get(filosofo), garfos.get((filosofo + 1) % N));
                } else {
                    ((SolucaoMonitor) vraSolucao.vraObject).largaGarfos(filosofo, garfos.get(filosofo), garfos.get((filosofo + 1) % N));
                }
                break;
            case SEMAFORO:
                if (booPega) {
                    ((SolucaoSemaforo) vraSolucao.vraObject).pegaGarfos(filosofo, garfos.get(filosofo), garfos.get((filosofo + 1) % N));
                } else {
                    ((SolucaoSemaforo) vraSolucao.vraObject).largaGarfos(filosofo, garfos.get(filosofo), garfos.get((filosofo + 1) % N));
                }
                break;
        }

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                // pensa ...
                pensaMuito(filosofo);
                // pega garfos
                executaGarfo(true);
                comeEspaguete(filosofo);
                // larga garfos
                executaGarfo(false);

            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void pensaMuito(int fil) {
        switch (fil) {
            case 0: // filosofo 0 pensa por 1000 ms...
                try {
                    System.out.println("!!>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " PENSA");
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            case 1: // filosofo 1 pensa por 2000 ms...
                try {
                    System.out.println("!!>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " PENSA");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            case 2: // filosofo 1 pensa por 3000 ms...
                try {
                    System.out.println("!!>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " PENSA");
                    Thread.sleep(1500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            case 3: // filosofo 1 pensa por 4000 ms...
                try {
                    System.out.println("!!>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " PENSA");
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            case 4: // filosofo 1 pensa por 5000 ms...
                try {
                    System.out.println("!!>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " PENSA");
                    Thread.sleep(2500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
        }
    }


    private void comeEspaguete(int fil) {
        System.out.println("@@>" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " COME ESPAGUETE");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

classe FilosofosGlutoes

```
public class FilosofosGlutoes {

    public enum TSolucaoEnum {
        SYNCHRONIZED, MONITOR, SEMAFORO;
    }
    public static class TSolucao {

        public TSolucaoEnum tpSolucaoEnum = TSolucaoEnum.SEMAFORO;
        public Object vraObject;

        public TSolucao() {
            switch (this.tpSolucaoEnum)
            {
                case SYNCHRONIZED: this.vraObject = new SolucaoSynchronized();
                    break;
                case MONITOR: this.vraObject = new SolucaoMonitor();
                    break;
                case SEMAFORO: this.vraObject = new SolucaoSemaforo();
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        // cria os grafos (cole��o de 5 garfos)
        List<Garfo> garfos = new ArrayList<Garfo>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
            Garfo garfo = new Garfo(i);
            garfos.add(i, garfo);
        }

        //Solução COM SYNCHRONIZED ->>DESCOMENTAR - Ctrl + Shift + C<<-             
        //Solução COM MONITOR ->>DESCOMENTAR - Ctrl + Shift + C<<-              
        TSolucao vraSolucao = new TSolucao();
        // cria a thread do filosofo 0
        FilosofoGlutao r0 = new FilosofoGlutao(garfos, 0, vraSolucao);
        Thread f0 = new Thread(r0);
        // cria a thread do filosofo 1
        FilosofoGlutao r1 = new FilosofoGlutao(garfos, 1, vraSolucao);
        Thread f1 = new Thread(r1);
        // cria a thread do filosofo 2
        FilosofoGlutao r2 = new FilosofoGlutao(garfos, 2, vraSolucao);
        Thread f2 = new Thread(r2);
        // cria a thread do filosofo 3
        FilosofoGlutao r3 = new FilosofoGlutao(garfos, 3, vraSolucao);
        Thread f3 = new Thread(r3);
        // cria a thread do filosofo 4
        FilosofoGlutao r4 = new FilosofoGlutao(garfos, 4, vraSolucao);
        Thread f4 = new Thread(r4);

        // nomeia as threads
        f0.setName("F0");
        f1.setName("F1");
        f2.setName("F2");
        f3.setName("F3");
        f4.setName("F4");

        // manda as threads pra fila de pronto
        f0.start();
        f1.start();
        f2.start();
        f3.start();
        f4.start();
    }
}
```

Classe Garfo:

```
public class Garfo{
    private int idGarfo;
    private boolean estadoGarfo;
    private int dono;

    public Garfo(int id){
        idGarfo = id;
        estadoGarfo = false; // desocupado      
        dono = -1; // sem dono
    }

    public int getIdGarfo(){
        return idGarfo;
    }

    public void setIdGarfo(int g){
        idGarfo = g;
    }

    public int getDonoGarfo(){
        return dono;
    }

    public void setDonoGarfo(int d){
        dono = d;   
    }

    public boolean getEstadoGarfo(){
        return estadoGarfo;
    }

    public void setEstadoGarfo(boolean ocupado){
        estadoGarfo = ocupado;
    }
}
```

Comment: Da uma olhada na resposta, tem um exemplo bem detalhado sobre `LinkedBlockingQueue` https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/204704/controle-global-para-executorservice

Comment: @PauloH.Hartmann Ok, muito obrigada! Vou dar uma olhada. :)